# SQL QUERY ERROR ; MUST BE AN INTEGER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting the following error in my SQL Query. Can anyone please help:

Msg 1060, Level 15, State 1, Line 50
The number of rows provided for a TOP or FETCH clauses row count parameter must be an integer.

```
with 
-- sample data
Tbl_PCode as (
select * 
from (values 
       (450001,cast('8/1/2016' as date), 'REG', 40.50, 1),
       (450001,cast('8/1/2016' as date), 'OT', 10.50,  2),

       (450002,cast('8/2/2016' as date), 'REG', 29.50, 3),                                    

       (450003,cast('8/3/2016' as date), 'REG', 32.50, 4),
       (450003,cast('8/3/2016' as date), 'VACC', 8.50, 5),

       (450004,cast('8/3/2016' as date), 'VACC', 8.50, 6),

       (450005,cast('8/3/2016' as date), 'VACC', 35.50,7)

       ) t(ID,Date,PCode,Hours,pos) 
), 
Tbl_TCode as (
select * 
from (values 
       (450001,cast('8/1/2016' as date), 'SHOPC', 10.50,  1),
       (450001,cast('8/1/2016' as date), 'FIELDC', 30.50, 2),
       (450001,cast('8/1/2016' as date), 'SHOPC', 2.00,   3),
       (450001,cast('8/1/2016' as date), 'FIELDC', 8.00,  4),  

       (450002,cast('8/2/2016' as date), 'SHOPC', 2.00,   5),
       (450002,cast('8/2/2016' as date), 'FIELDC', 27.50, 6),

       (450003,cast('8/3/2016' as date), 'SHOPC', 20.50,  7),
       (450003,cast('8/3/2016' as date), 'FIELDC', 12.50, 8),
       (450003,cast('8/3/2016' as date), 'SHOPC', 8.00,   9),
       (450003,cast('8/3/2016' as date), 'FIELDC', 0.00,  10),

       (450004,cast('8/3/2016' as date), 'SHOPC', 8.50,   11),

       (450005,cast('8/3/2016' as date), 'SHOPC', 35.50,  12)

       ) t(ID,Date,TCode,Hours,pos)
), 
tally as ( 
 select top(500000) rn= row_number() over(order by (select null))
 from sys.all_objects
),
-- query
t_P as (
select *, rn=row_number() over(partition by ID,Date order by pos)  
from Tbl_PCode
cross apply (select top(Hours) 1 n 
             from tally
            ) x
), 
t_T as (
select *, rn=row_number() over(partition by ID,Date order by pos)  
from Tbl_TCode
cross apply (select top(Hours) 1 n 
             from tally
            ) x
)
select t_P.ID as PersonNum, t_P.Date, t_P.PCode as PayCode, 
count(*) as  Hours, t_T.TCode as TransferCode
from t_P
join t_T on t_P.ID=t_T.ID and t_P.Date=t_T.Date and t_P.rn=t_T.rn
group by t_P.ID, t_P.Date, t_P.PCode, t_T.TCode
order by t_P.id asc
```

Comment: What is this supposed to be doing:  `select top(Hours) 1 n `?

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
cross apply (select top(Hours) 1 n
```

to

```
cross apply (select top 1 [Hours] AS n
```

in both CROSS APPLY statements. It's just a syntax error.

Comment: It isn't a syntax error it is a datatype error. The syntax they have is valid but hours is numeric not int. if it is cast to int the query works fine. http://rextester.com/MDSUL60170. Whether or not that has sensible semantics isn't something I have bothered to check though.

Comment: Sorry.  The results in the table need to show in decimals and not in INT. Yes the Query works fine but it is not calculating correctly.

Comment: Example: 450001 total hours should come to 51 hours but your calculation is showing 50 hours.

Comment: The question was on the syntax error, but I have no idea what this query is trying to do. Let us know what the output should look like and we'll let you know how to get there.